# How to add a filter in django for every request?

Tags: python, django, http, security

I want to add a security filter so that every request to my django app will go through the filter first and then let the request go through if the token from the header is valid.

How can I accomplish that in django?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new middleware like this:

```
class SecurityMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        token = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')
        if token != "Some Value":
             return HttpResponse('Unauthorized', status=401)
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

Then add this to the `MIDDLEWARE` in `settings.py`.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'path.to.SecurityMiddleware'
]
```

More information can be found in [custom middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/middleware/) documentation and [request and response object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/) documentation.

FYI, if you want to implement a standard authentication system like JWT or basic auths, consider using thrid party libraries like Simple JWT with Django Rest Framework or so on.